# Twig - if object contains one element

Tags: symfony, twig

I want to use an if statement in my twig for cycle - if object(variable) contains one element(row) - then add this html code snippet,

And here's what I'm trying,

```
{% for course in courses %}
    <a href="{{ course.courseLink }}"class="courses">
        <div class="picture"><img src="{{ asset('/bundles/dproc/assets/images/courses-       example.jpg') }}" alt="news-1" title="news-1" /></div>
        <div class="title"><h2>{{ course.courseTitle }}</h2></div>
        <div class="info">
        {{ course.courseContent }}
        </div>
     </a>
{% endfor %}
```

at the moment `courses` contains only one element. My task is to add a `div` element if it contains only one element.

- How can I do that in twig?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use this function to check the [length](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/filters/length.html) of an array

```
{% if courses|length == 1 %}
    {# print div#}
{% endif %}
```